# Configuring spring-cloud loadbalancer without autoconfiguration

Tags: spring-cloud

I've read whole documentation, tutorial [1], and spend several hours in sources, but I still do not understand how to configure loadbalancer, especially if I don't use magic annotations.

I have following configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    public static final String SERVICE_ID = "service";

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public ServiceInstanceListSupplier serviceInstanceListSupplier() {
        return ServiceInstanceListSuppliers.from(SERVICE_ID,
                new DefaultServiceInstance(SERVICE_ID + "1", SERVICE_ID, "localhost", 8886, false),
                new DefaultServiceInstance(SERVICE_ID + "2", SERVICE_ID, "localhost", 8887, false));
    }

    @Bean
    public LoadBalancerClientFactory loadBalancerClientFactory() {
        return new LoadBalancerClientFactory();
    }

    @Bean
    public ReactorLoadBalancerExchangeFilterFunction loadBalancerExchangeFilterFunction(LoadBalancerProperties properties) {
        return new ReactorLoadBalancerExchangeFilterFunction(loadBalancerClientFactory(), properties);
    }
}
```

and use bean `loadBalancerExchangeFilterFunction` as:

```
WebClient.builder()
            .baseUrl("http://service/test-consumer")
            .filter(lbFunction)
            .build();
```

and it works. The problem is, that it works **regardless** of what hostname I use. So if I replace hostname "service" with whatever work I like, I will be still sending data to localhost:8886 or localhost:8887.

Can someone explain what is the role of serviceId and how this is paired to collection of DefaultServiceInstance?

(I want to understand the internals, what are the key components, their purpose and their interplay. I'm not primarily looking for magic annotation, but that one actually explained would be also great. Debugging it is really hard, I have several A4 with class diagrams and it still makes no sense at all).

**Question**: Is there a misconfiguration? What is the purpose of serviceId? It seems that none, as webclient using `ReactorLoadBalancerExchangeFilterFunction` will create roundrobin loadbalancer over configured ServiceInstances regardless of what is actual hostname used in given webclient.

**Question2**: how could I create 2 loadbalanced services and control to which service (not node) will request go? Do I need 2 separate webclients or some url pattern(like using serviceId in place of hostname) will do? If I need 2 webclients, how is pairing to DefaultServiceInstance done?

[1] https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-cloud-loadbalancer/

---

EDIT:

after suggested update, the configuration looks like:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public ServiceInstanceListSupplier instanceSupplier(ConfigurableApplicationContext context) {
        return ServiceInstanceListSupplier.builder()
                .withDiscoveryClient()
                .withHealthChecks()
                .build(context);
    }

    @Bean
    public LoadBalancerClientFactory loadBalancerClientFactory() {
        return new LoadBalancerClientFactory();
    }

    @Bean
    public ReactorLoadBalancerExchangeFilterFunction loadBalancerExchangeFilterFunction(LoadBalancerProperties properties) {
        return new ReactorLoadBalancerExchangeFilterFunction(loadBalancerClientFactory(), properties);
    }
}
```

application.properties contains:

```
spring.cloud.discovery.client.simple.instances.complicated[0].uri=http://localhost:8886
spring.cloud.discovery.client.simple.instances.complicated[1].uri=http://localhost:8887
```

webclient call to URL: `http://localhost:8888/test-consumer` (ie. hostname not matching serviceID) produces:

```
o.s.c.l.core.RoundRobinLoadBalancer      : No servers available for service: localhost
eactorLoadBalancerExchangeFilterFunction : LoadBalancer does not contain an instance for the service localhost
```

webclient call to URL: `http://complicated/test-consumer` (ie. hostname matching serviceID) produces:

```
o.s.c.l.core.RoundRobinLoadBalancer      : No servers available for service: complicated
eactorLoadBalancerExchangeFilterFunction : LoadBalancer does not contain an instance for the service complicated
```

The reason for this is that `this.serviceId = environment.getProperty(PROPERTY_NAME);` in `DiscoveryClientServiceInstanceListSupplier(ReactiveDiscoveryClient,Environment)` evaluates as null, thus even though I'm looking for some serviceId, `delegate.getInstance` is called with null, so no ServiceInstances are found.  IF I removed @Bean instanceSupplier, and hope for autoconfiguration do it somehow magically, the `this.serviceId = environment.getProperty(PROPERTY_NAME);` is somehow magically set, serviceId is propagated correctly, and it works. For calls which leads elsewhere than configured serviceId, it fails saying, that this serviceId is not know, instead of making call.

**SO it does mean**, that if I configure loadbalancer, I cannot call anything else but (auto)configured services???

Comment: While using the auto-configured loadbalancer, serviceId is used as a key to get information from servicediscovery. You've configured a static `ServiceInstanceListSupplier`, which is primarily for testing. If you use a `DiscoveryClientServiceInstanceListSupplier` in combination with `SimpleDiscoveryClient` https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-commons/issues/821#issuecomment-789768200 then servicId will again serve as a key to instances. Much of the autoconfiguration is done so spring beans can be used to configure different behavior per serviceid.

Comment: Ok, that cleared black spots around configuring ServiceInstances via property file. Thanks! So say I did the change you suggested. How `ReactorLoadBalancerExchangeFilterFunction` will know what serviceId to load from `DiscoveryClientServiceInstanceListSupplier`? How is the pairing done? Is it based on hostname-from-original-uri == serviceId?

Comment: Yes, it's by the hostname.

Comment: I've tried to adapt code based on your recommendation, and it does not seem to be working. — Well I'm really guessing how correct configuration could look like, as I'm not able to find any full example anywhere; any tutorial, documentation, anything. Can you show full configuration or provide link to any place where it is shown? I will try to proceed with debugging spring-cloud internals to find out what is happening, but it's very complicated there, so I don't expect to be successful.

Comment: ... `this.serviceId = environment.getProperty(PROPERTY_NAME);` in `DiscoveryClientServiceInstanceListSupplier(ReactiveDiscoveryClient,Environment)` evaluate as null, thus even though I'm looking for some serviceId, `delegate.getInstance` is called with null. So it seems that `DiscoveryClientServiceInstanceListSupplier` is also related to single serviceId. So there must be missing something which sets this environment varible or something. It's extremely puzzling

Comment: ok. This is DEFINITELY a bug. I can see that value `complicated` `loadbalancer.client.name` is being registered in `org.springframework.cloud.context.named.NamedContextFactory#createContext` as MapPropertySource, I can access it and verify that it is set, but later in flow `environment.getProperty("loadbalancer.client.name")` returns null. I tried to find out, what mystical way brings ServiceInstanceListSupplier to life correctly and what makes the difference,but no autoconfiguration from LoadBalancerClientConfiguration is used.

Comment: It's 2022 and Spring Cloud 2021.0.1 and I got to the same point where I see the expression `this.serviceId = environment.getProperty(PROPERTY_NAME);` having `null` value in the constructor of `DiscoveryClientServiceInstanceListSupplier` class...

Answer (score 2):

The LoadBalancer config should not be in a `@Configuration`-annotated class; instead, it should be a class passed for config via `@LoadBalancerClient` or `@LoadBalancerClients` annotation, as described [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-commons/docs/current/reference/html/#custom-loadbalancer-configuration).

Also, the only bean you need to instantiate is the `ServiceInstanceListSupplier` (if you add `spring-cloud-starter-loadbalancer`, `LoadBalancerClientFactory`, and `ReactorLoadBalancerExchangeFilterFunction` will be instantiated by the starter).

So your LoadBalancer configuration class will look like so (without `@Configuration`):

```
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public ServiceInstanceListSupplier instanceSupplier(ConfigurableApplicationContext context) {
        return ServiceInstanceListSupplier.builder()
                .withDiscoveryClient()
                .withHealthChecks()
                .build(context);
    }

}
```

and your actual `@Configuration` class (for example, where you configure other webflux-related beans), will have the following annotation: `@LoadBalancerClients(defaultConfiguration = AppConfig.class)`.

Then, if you enable health-checks in the `complicated` instances, it should work without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, able to resolve this issue with the below Configuration. not sure why it works only with Non blocking approach and when we pass the new RestTemplate

```
@Bean
    public ServiceInstanceListSupplier instanceSupplier(ConfigurableApplicationContext context) {
        return ServiceInstanceListSupplier.builder()
                .withDiscoveryClient()
                .withBlockingHealthChecks(new RestTemplate())//this change
                .build(context);
    }
```